# How to determine the coordinates of the points of parallel line?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njtUv.png)

Look at the picture.
I've coordinates of P1, P2 and lenght of AB. How can I find P3(x3;y3) at least? The parallel line should always be on the left of initial line! I need a formula, I have to program it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $P_1, P_2, P_4, P_3$ form a rectangle you can calculate the vector $\vec{AB}$ as following:

The line $g$ through $P_1, P_2$ has the form $y=y_1 + (y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1) \cdot (x-x_1)$. Every line orthogonal to $g$ hence has gradient $m:=-(x_2-x_1)/(y_2-y_1)$. Hence $(y_3-y_1)/(x_3-x_1)=-1/m$ since they lay on a line orthogonal to $g$.

On the other hand using Pythagoras we get $(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2= \bar{AB}^2$.

I think you can now overtake from here (just plug in equations), if not don't hesitate to ask further.

**Remark:** If they don't form a rectangle, this problem has no unique solution, since you can move your points $P_3, P_4$ along this parallel line without changing the length of $AB$.

Comment: If I try to plug in I get a very huge formula for y3. I got it earlier when I tried to get this formula by myself. It does very big computing and work using very huge numbers=( I thought another method exists.

Comment: This formula shouldn't be so big. Just do it in several steps and use your values in between, you are using a computer anyway. Don't try to do it in one formula, instead try to keep the calculations at a minimum by using intermediate results (as e.g. $m, x_3$).

Answer (score 0):

1. compute the coordinates of $\overrightarrow{P_1 P_2} = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1)$
2. $\overrightarrow{A B}$ is orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{P_1 P_2}$ so it's proportional to $\overrightarrow{h} = (y_1 - y_2, x_2 - x_1)$
3. Compute coordinates of $\overrightarrow{A B}$ and add them to the coordinates of $P_1$. Don't forget there are two cases - to the one and to the another side of $(P_1 P_2)$ line.